# How can I overcome the lack of Auto Exposure Bracketing (AEB) in NIKON D3300?

Tags: bracketing, nikon-d3300

Recently bought D3300, switching over from Canon 1200D. 1200D has AEB feature with 3 shots for making HDR photos, and I used this feature with ease and great delight.

Now, how can I overcome this limitation of not having AEB in D3300? Ideally I would like to take 3 consecutive shots with -1, 0, +1 EV (D3300 can take 5 shots in burst mode though).

Answer (score 2):

Fix your camera on a tripod, set it to M(anual) mode and adjust the shutter speed manually.

Comment: Should have added, I mostly travel handheld. So tripod is a no no for me most of the time. Is there any custom firmware available or modification can be done in the settings to enable AEB in D3300?